# How to append some logic before a function using Test::MockModule?

Tags: perl

This is the mock module I'm using:

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockModule](http://metacpan.org/pod/Test%3a%3aMockModule)

How to mock `sub a` to `sub b`,

where `sub b` just does something else before call `sub a`?

```
sub b {
  #do something else
  a(@_);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the un-mocked method with `can` ( `UNIVERSAL::can` ). After that you can either `goto` it or just use the ampersand calling style to pass the same arguments. That's what I did below.

```
 my $old_a = Package::To::Be::Mocked->can( 'a' );
 $pkg->mock( a => sub { 
      # do some stuff
      &$old_a;
 });
```

This of course assumes that your sub isn't `AUTOLOAD` or generated through `AUTOLOAD` without redefining `can`. (I learned years back that if you're going to mess with `AUTOLOAD`, it's probably best to do the work in `can`.)

You could also create your own utility that does this automatically, by <strike>invading</strike> modifying the `Test::MockModule`'s namespace.

```
{   package Test::MockModule;
    sub modify {
        my ( $self, $name, $modfunc ) = @_;
        my $mock_class = $self->get_package();
        my $old_meth = $mock_class->can( $name );
        croak( "Method $name not defined for $mock_class!" ) unless $old_meth;
        return $self->mock( $name => $modfunc->( $old_meth ));
    }
}
```

And you could call it like so:

```
$mock->modify( a => sub { 
    my $old_a = shift;
    return sub { 
        my ( $self ) = @_;
        # my stuff and I can mess with $self
        local $Carp::CarpLevel += 1;
        my @returns = &$old_a;
        # do stuff with returns
        return @returns;
    };
});
```

Comment: How do I mock an inherited functin?

Comment: @new_perl, if you simply want to override the behavior defined in a parent class, mock should work for that. `can` hands back a reference to the sub that it dispatches to--if using the default can or the programmer knew what he or she was doing. So `modify` *should* work as well, but in the case that you simply want to override parent function, you could also use the standard `$self->SUPER::a( @_ );` (as long as `$self` has been shifted from the "deck".)